# Как сделать styled button disabled

Tags: css, reactjs

У меня есть кнопка, хотя это тег `<a>`

```js
    const AddPostBtn = styled.a`
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 300;
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 16px;
      color: #ffffff;
      background: #67bfff;
      box-shadow: 8px 10px 25px rgba(148, 174, 213, 0.15);
      border-radius: 10px;
      position: absolute;
      width: 139px;
      height: 25px;
      left: 50%;
      top: 25px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      transform: translate(-50%);
      cursor: pointer;
    `;
```

я хочу чтобы в зависимости от состояния(state), у меня кнопка отключалась(disabling),

```html
      <AddPostBtn
        disabled={showBtn}
        onClick={() => router.push(href)}
      >
        {text}
      </AddPostBtn>
```

showBtn - это состояния(state), он меняется, всё ок, но кнопка не отключалась(disabling). Возможно это из-за styled я в них не силен, подскажите как здесь это реализовать.

Comment: может дело в   cursor: pointer уберите его

Comment: я крч проверил, но тип та ну, какой поинтер... нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может это вам поможет

```css
.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://google.com" class="disabled">ТЕСТ</a><br/>
<a href="https://google.com">ТЕСТ</a>
```

Comment: Спасибо, это конечно работает и сам хотел через стили, но ведь это наверное не правильно, это же нужно прописывать в html типа disabled={true}, а ваше решение выглядит как костыль, что если мне нужно будет использовать не disabled, а например active or focus, может я конечно и не прав, но должен же быть решение в styled похожее на disabled={true}

Comment: @АлексейМелентьев нет, это не костыльно, в браузере это будет одинаково отрабатывать